# Как перехватить нажатия клавиш?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу калькулятор под `WPF`. На данный момент нажатие на кнопки производит запись данных в `textbox`, но хотелось бы чтобы при нажатии цифр на клавиатуре они были забиндены к методам, т.е. чтобы тупо было перехват кнопок. Делать через `WinApi` думаю будет слишком избыточно, нет ли в самом `WPF` такого?

```
  private void One_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (totalled == true)
            {
                Display.Content = "";
                totalled = false;
            }
            Display.Content += "1";
            storageVariable += "1";
        }
        private void Two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (totalled == true)
            {
                Display.Content = "";
                totalled = false;
            }
            Display.Content += "2";
            storageVariable += "2";
        }
        private void Three_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (totalled == true)
            {
                Display.Content = "";
                totalled = false;
            }
            Display.Content += "3";
            storageVariable += "3";
        }
        private void Four_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (totalled == true)
            {
                Display.Content = "";
                totalled = false;
            }
            Display.Content += "4";
            storageVariable += "4";
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего подписаться на события `KeyDown` или `PreviewKeyDown` в окне.

Порядок доставки такой: сначала приходит `PreviewKeyDown` окну, затем по цепочке внутрь контролу, у которого фокус, потом приходит `KeyDown` контролу, и по цепочке вверх к окну.

Если вам не нужны на уровне окна нажатия на служебные клавиши, которые обработает `TextBox` (left/right/del), подписывайтесь на `KeyDown`. `PreviewKeyDown` позволяет также заблокировать ввод текста (например, вы хотите запретить ввод буквы `A`), и получает всё подряд.

Пример:

```
<Window ...
    PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown">
    ...
</Window>
```

```
void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var key = e.Key;
    if (key == Key.A)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```